# Send Specific variables through socket.io to client with socket.send

Tags: arrays, node.js, sockets, socket.io

How do I send and pick-up a certain variable when using socket.send. I am trying to send separate variables which are arrays of text.  I am using node.js to send specific data to the client (html).

I know what I have is wrong with the 'message'  but I don't know how to send a specific variable when I want to.

Server

```
var serv_io = io.listen(htmlServer, { log: false });
serv_io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    jsonResults = JSON.stringify(ResultsArray);
    jsonTime = JSON.stringify(TimeArray); 

    socket.send(jsonResults);                           
    socket.send(jsonTime);
```

Client

```
var socket = io.connect();
   socket.on('message', function(message){        
   var resultsobj= jQuery.parseJSON(message);
   var timeobj = jQuery.parseJSON(message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it all together in a single object:

```
allTheThings = JSON.stringify({
    'results': ResultsArray,
    'time': TimeArray });

socket.send(allTheThings);
```

Comment: What do I use on the cliend side. What I have is not picking up the messages

Comment: You just parse the message.  If it's still not working, update your question.

Comment: It is till not working I updated the question to show an example of what I get through socket.io (normally it is filled with data and is more complex arrays within arrays)  I simplified it for my question

Comment: what would be the syntax for picking up the arrays

Comment: It works now.  The fix was using obj.results[1] to call the variables using arrays inside arrays.